# raspberry pi 4b, python, opencv, When trying to process video frames the instructions do not run sequentially

Tags: python, camera, pyqt5

I have a problem when executing the programme below, So basically what's happening is when I execute the programme I expect it to open the camera (logitec usb camera) capture a frame, process it, recognize the object, send a command to Arduino to rotate a motor to flip the object to fall and liberate the space for another object, wait for half a second then repeat the process all over again until the condition is satisfied. But what happens is when I execute the programme, at first it detects nothing (which is good because there's actually nothing)
then when I introduce an object it keeps detecting nothing for about 5-8 frames then it detects the object and it keeps detecting it even when I remove it or gets dropped for about 5-8 frames (which causes the platform to rotate about 5-8 times) and so on. as I said, I need to capture a frame process it and recognize the object, drop it with the motor then and until then repeat the process.

That's the code I'm working on:

```py
def predict(self):
        print('start predicting : ' + str(self.started))
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 640)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
        while self.started is True and self.token is not None:
            print("predicting")
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                return
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            cv2_im = frame.copy()
            cv2_im = cv2.resize(cv2_im, (self.height, self.width))
            img_array = np.asarray(cv2_im * 1. / 255, dtype='float32')
            predictions = self.lite_model(img_array[None, ...])[0] # Prediction process, it takes 1.3-1.7 sec
            y_lite = np.argmax(predictions)
            self.save_operation(y_lite) # this is a thread
            class_name = self.getClass(y_lite)
            print("class_name = "+class_name)
            if class_name == "object1":
                self.serial.write(b'r')
                print("turn right")
                sleep(.8)
            elif class_name == "object2":
                self.serial.write(b'l')
                print("turn left")
                sleep(.8)
            self.save_img(frame, class_name) # this is a thread

        cap.release()
```

I managed to make it work by turning on and off the camera for each frame but that resulted in another problem (camera start timeout) which i solved by adding a sleep(1.2) to let the camera takes it's time to be shutdown, but this is not good as it takes more time then it should to complete the process and I need to be fast.

```py
def predict(self):
        print('start predicting : ' + str(self.started))
        
        while self.started is True and self.token is not None:
            print("predicting")
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # Turn on the camera
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 640)
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
            ret, frame = cap.read() # read a frame
            if not ret:
                return
            cap.release() # Release Camera resources
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            cv2_im = frame.copy()
            cv2_im = cv2.resize(cv2_im, (self.height, self.width))
            img_array = np.asarray(cv2_im * 1. / 255, dtype='float32')
            predictions = self.lite_model(img_array[None, ...])[0] # Prediction process, it takes 1.3-1.7 sec
            y_lite = np.argmax(predictions)
            self.save_operation(y_lite) # this is a thread
            class_name = self.getClass(y_lite)
            print("class_name = "+class_name)
            if class_name == "object1":
                self.serial.write(b'r')
                print("turn right")
            elif class_name == "object2":
                self.serial.write(b'l')
                print("turn left")
            self.save_img(frame, class_name) # this is a thread
            sleep(1.2) # For the camera to shutdown properly
```

The whole process now takes about 3 sec. but if you miss putting the object at the right time it could take up to 5 sec, but I'm hoping I could get it to take less than 2 sec.

Capture a frame -> process it (1.3-1.7 sec) -> drop it (half a sec)-> capture a frame->...

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Maybe predictions of your model are incorrect or you are misinterpreting the experimental results. Anyway, if you remedied the code by introducing some delays, why not ignore captured frames during a delay?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but how can I ignore captured frames during the delay? I believe what's happening is that  the loop is storing the process in a pool of threads while executing the next process (it doesn't wait for the current process to finish).

Comment: No it does not work like that. Print logs with time stamps and double check that. Anyway , by 'ignore frames' I mean calling cap.read() in the loop and doing a prediction only if a certain condition is met, where that condition depends on the timestamp.